# Node js reuse existing buff call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code which works as expected however I wonder if there is a way to improve is as Im doing `New Buffer` twice.
I need to encode two values now but **more** latter... , user and password.

I mean reduce boilerplate code

```
let secret = await getSecret("mt", "fe");
let adminBuff = new Buffer(secret.admin, 'base64');
let admin = adminBuff.toString('ascii');
let adminPass = new Buffer(secret.pass, 'base64');
let pass = adminPass.toString('ascii');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) since [`new Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding) is deprecated.

As for the reusability part, creating a function would be helpful. Something like the following:

```
function toAsciiString (value) {
    const valueBuff = Buffer.from(value, 'base64');
    return valueBuff.toString('ascii');
}

let secret = await getSecret("mt", "fe");
let admin = toAsciiString(secret.admin);
let pass = toAsciiString(secret.pass);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the keys of the object "secret", process their values and create a new object containing the processing results.

For example:

```
let secret = await getSecret("mt", "fe");
const resultObj = {};
Object.keys(secret).forEach((key) => {
    const newBuffer = new Buffer(secret[key], 'base64');
    resultObj[key] = newBuffer.toString('ascii');
});
```